# JavaScript void performance

Tags: javascript, performance, function, return, void

If my script executes a function that returns e.g. a huge object that I don't want to use or store, is it better/faster/less memory intensive to call that function with the void operator? Or will it decrease the performance because the return value will just be overwritten?

```
void myFunc();
```

Just created a test:

http://jsperf.com/voidperf

Comment: So you already tested this yourself, hey?

Comment: I got 1.16% slower using void on your test. Followed by .80%. I think that there is really no affect of using void in that scenario.

Comment: Your jsperf tests don't show much difference. So I guess you answered your own question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `void` operator is only used to obtain the `undefined` primitive value; it can be useful when you run code in `javascript:` inline mode, because the page won't get replaced by the return value (casted to string) if it's `undefined`.

Therefore, there's no appreciable difference between these two constructs:

```
getSuperBigResult();
void getSuperBigResult();
```

JavaScript will run both in a void'ish manner, because the former statement doesn't use the return value either.

See also: [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)